# Unable to get script tag's content from a scraped page using xpath, lxml

Tags: python, html, xpath, n-gram

I'm writing a python program and as part of it I need to extract data from google ngram viewer. For example for the search:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Godfather&year_start=1972-&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3

I need the graph values from this tag:

```
  var data = [{"ngram": "The Godfather", "type": "NGRAM", "timeseries": [1.4183381225052472e-07, 1.4025288521679614e-07, 1.5749316872870622e-07, 1.618123600824869e-07, 1.7873649125834034e-07, 1.8325580697364785e-07, 1.838378673418057e-07, 1.7964884234191102e-07, 1.7921279850595185e-07, 1.8174738970953642e-07, 1.7919142944070439e-07, 1.7377866307859741e-07, 1.6968103417574249e-07, 1.6785447241675554e-07, 1.698323818085815e-07, 1.7567729011196726e-07, 1.7198440259237812e-07, 1.6793204338227952e-07, 1.7446684604952418e-07, 1.8290416343396438e-07, 1.8512590876136009e-07, 1.8604621183320497e-07, 1.9866517269357636e-07, 1.8994029866397405e-07, 2.0815326909736802e-07, 2.2254876138764042e-07, 2.2457939508058189e-07, 2.5743728875633156e-07, 2.7453169236326046e-07, 2.7866381507075335e-07, 3.0070588609630378e-07, 3.0204388273042629e-07, 2.9686912585345583e-07, 2.9399397760698776e-07, 2.7703356645740013e-07, 2.7225316614476467e-07, 2.6805425434872632e-07], "parent": ""}];
  if (data.length > 0) {
    ngrams.drawD3Chart(data, 1972, 2008, 1.0, "main");
  }
```

I've tried using lxml to convert the HTML into a tree then used the xpath copied from the site like this:

```
page = requests.get('https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Godfather&year_start=1972-&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

nGramData = tree.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/script[11]/text()')
```

However if I then try to print nGramData I get no result, what am I doing wrong or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Use the following working code:**

```
>>> page = requests.get('https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Godfather&year_start=1972-&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
>>> nGramData = tree.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/script')
>>> nGramData[6].text_content()
'\n  var data = [{"ngram": "The Godfather", "type": "NGRAM", "timeseries": [1.4183381225052472e-07, 1.4025288521679614e-07, 1.5749316872870622e-07, 1.618123600824869e-07, 1.7873649125834034e-07, 1.8325580697364785e-07, 1.838378673418057e-07, 1.7964884234191102e-07, 1.7921279850595185e-07, 1.8174738970953642e-07, 1.7919142944070439e-07, 1.7377866307859741e-07, 1.6968103417574249e-07, 1.6785447241675554e-07, 1.698323818085815e-07, 1.7567729011196726e-07, 1.7198440259237812e-07, 1.6793204338227952e-07, 1.7446684604952418e-07, 1.8290416343396438e-07, 1.8512590876136009e-07, 1.8604621183320497e-07, 1.9866517269357636e-07, 1.8994029866397405e-07, 2.0815326909736802e-07, 2.2254876138764042e-07, 2.2457939508058189e-07, 2.5743728875633156e-07, 2.7453169236326046e-07, 2.7866381507075335e-07, 3.0070588609630378e-07, 3.0204388273042629e-07, 2.9686912585345583e-07, 2.9399397760698776e-07, 2.7703356645740013e-07, 2.7225316614476467e-07, 2.6805425434872632e-07], "parent": ""}];\n  if (data.length > 0) {\n    ngrams.drawD3Chart(data, 1972, 2008, 1.0, "main");\n  }\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use BeautifulSoup and Json:

open and read the link (might be urllib2 in Python 3):

```
link=urllib.urlopen("https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+Godfather&year_start=1972-&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20Godfather%3B%2Cc0")
content=link.read()
```

Turn it into a BeautifulSoup element, after importing BS from bs4:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
extract=soup.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')[4].string
```

Use a regular expression to get something to read into JSON (need to import), then extract just the time series:

```
data=re.findall('(\[.*\])', extract)

t=json.loads(data[0])
result= t[0]['timeseries']
```